# Exchange Server Transport Rule Failing Emails From .mil

Tags: email, outlook, exchange-server

I am using Exchange Server 2013 and have many transport rules set up to filter out emails from most countries outside of the US.

We recently received an email from a military email, ending in .mil

The email was blocked by my transport rules but does not match any of the extensions I have listed. Except for possibly one! I have an extension to block '.il$'. So this should block ALL emails that end with ".il". However, if the transport rules use true regular expression rules, the "." would be a wildchar and match any and every character including a "." itself. Is this the cause of my issue? I do not have a .mil email account to test with or I could check myself. I have added a character escape to my transport rule, making it '\.il$' hoping that it will fix this.

I read everything I can find about the regex rules for Exchange's Transport Rules, and I cannot find anything that mentions you must escape the dot. Maybe this is just a rare issue and they didn't foresee it occurring?

One of the documents I have read: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997187(v=exchg.141).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short: YES, the dot(.) must be escaped with a \. Otherwise it is a single wildchar that matches any character [A-Z a-z 0-9 . , /] etc. just like in regular expression. I assume that Microsoft is using every rule from regular expression for the transport rules but do not quote me on that.

This cannot be found in any documentation that I have researched, it also seems that every example that I have looked at on the web has been doing it wrong as well. Examples that I see are always ".com$" will block all emails from a sender ending in .com. This is true because the dot can also be a dot. But this will also block any emails that end in "ecom" for example, which may be an issue if they ever decide to release such extension.

Sorry for answering my own question, but I want this to be here for future reference since it can't seem to be found anywhere else.